# Network-capable small format display?

Tags: networking, hardware, display

I am working on a project for per-station messaging and other functions in a warehouse. I don't want the cost of a full computer at each station, so I'm looking for small format hardware that I can push messages to.

My first thought was networked LCD's ( http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/twatch-v2-with-lcd-assembled-p-510.html?cPath=138 ), but then I thought further and would like something with a browser if I can, as it can look nicer.

My thought was to have cheap Android smartphones locked in to each workstation. This would provide a touchscreen and Opera browser, as well as being network capable.

Does anyone have any other hardware suggestions that might fit the bill better? I'm mainly looking for something with a browser.

Comment: how about a touch screen rdp based system.  Also I wouldn't buy smartphones for this I'd just buy one of the cheap android tablets.  Got mine for $130 from fry's its a coby!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of Cisco phones which are pretty much setup for this, and not so great Android tablets I would look at the Chumby:

http://www.chumby.com/

For more real estate, the iPod touch and iPad are the most realistic options for products that are not going to disappear over night and have a future.

**edit:** The far stretch is a USB monitor connected to the host computer and running additional customised software for it.  However the price and complexity easily exceed getting a completely independent and more powerful device such as capacitive touch screen and third part support.

http://www.thinkgeek.com/computing/usb-gadgets/c609/

Comment: We've started deploying iPads in our workforce for this sort of thing; it's been brilliant. Biggest issue is physical security - they are popular items for theft.

Comment: @Mark although not directly supported by Apple it looks like there are however many "[security solutions](http://www.maclocks.com/i-pad-lock.html)" appearing.